# React Native Redux access state from config file

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I am trying to access redux state from a config file to choose between 2 objects of colors to export to my classes.

I am able to access react native's Appearance API here which works. But if a user wants to toggle Light or Dark mode from the app, then this state needs to be read in order to do so.

I feel like I am almost there, I just would like some clarification and guidance as to why this isn't working as I expect it to.

```
//src/config.js

import {Appearance} from 'react-native';
import {store} from '../configureStore';

const mutualColors = {
  skizzuGreen: '#73C35B',
  secondaryGreen: '#54ad38',
  secondaryPurple: '#955ad8',
  secondaryOrange: '#e66f00',
  purple: '#7E57C2',
  orange: '#FF9800',
  white: '#ffffff',
};

const lightTheme = {
  background: '#fff',
  grayIcon: '#a6a6a6',
  backgroundAlt: '#F8F8F8',
  inputBackground: '#f0f0f0',
  inputBackgroundFocused: '#e6e6e6',
  blackText: '#262626',
  blackLight: '#595959',
  border: '#ccc',
  borderLight: '#e2e2e2',
};

const darkTheme = {
  background: '#121212',
  grayIcon: '#a6a6a6',
  backgroundAlt: '#262626',
  inputBackground: '#333333',
  inputBackgroundFocused: '#404040',
  blackText: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.87)',
  blackLight: '#b3b3b3',
  border: '#404040',
  borderLight: '#262626',
};

// devices color scheme (works) 
const colorSchemeDevice = Appearance.getColorScheme();

//Redux state is toggled on UI, state is setting correctly, but not able to access on app launch here.
const themeMode = store.getState().appThemeMode;

const dark = {...darkTheme, ...mutualColors};
const light = {...lightTheme, ...mutualColors};

//here we are exporting color
const colors =
  colorSchemeDevice === 'dark' && themeMode !== 'light' ? dark : light;

export default colors;
```

Comment: This code is all at the module level, so it will all run when the module is loaded, and then never again. Which means that the `default colors` will never change. To make it reactive I think you'll want to 1. put the colors on redux and dispatch an action to recalc it when color mode changes, 2. put the colors in a react store and dispatch an action when the color mode changes so consumers will get the update.

Comment: @windowsill Thanks for the quick response! That is helpful, but do you think I can avoid redux and move / change my config.js file to a new location in order for this to work? I have many `color.colorName` (styles) across my application and am looking to keep it this way but with a dynamic change for the object.